# Is there a more efficient way to group-up a label with an input field so that they become block-like?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make a HTML form for a webpage that is re-size-able ranging form full HD to smartphones. I want the distance form the label to the input to be the same distance such that if the form was to be placed in a div that for instance is 600px and the label and input field as line totals to 300px (including padding,margin, etc) that the fields order in 2 columns. If the div than after re-size would become 900px the form would spread over 3 columns.

The fields should then be ordered in the following manner:

with 2 columns:

```
F1  F4
F2  F5
F3  F6
```

with 3 columns:

```
F1  F3  F5
F2  F4  F6
```

Now since i am relatively new to HTML and CSS i personally would do this with a lot of div's but that seems a little bit redundant or just as really bad coding. I tried to do this with a `<span style="width:300px;">` but the span wont be 300 px nor will it include the input field.

my current form:

```
  <div class='main_text' style='width:55%;padding-left:10%;padding-right:10%;'>
     <label>Name:</label>
     <input id="name" type="text" value='Name'/><br />
     Age:
     <input id="age" type="text" value='21'/><br />
     Insterests:
     <input id="interests" type="text" value='Socer'/><br />
     Targets:
     <input id="targets" type="text" value='stop smoking for at least 2 years'/><br/>
     Other:
     <input id="other" type="text" value='I have 3 cats'/><br />
 </div>
```

So the question in short is:

Is there a more efficient way to group-up a label with an input field so that they become block-like?

P.S. Im using XHTML 1.0 transitional

Comment: You can use `<label for="someID">` to logically group elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: Semantically speaking, using a span to group your elements is no different than using a div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at existing frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) that will provide you with a good base to start writing a responsive design.

For the record, a `span` is an inline element hence you cannot define a width on it. Declare it as `display: inline-block;` and you'll notice the width property is now respected.

Comment: Advertisements don't seem appropriate for answers, especially when they have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Both of those frameworks provide out-of-the-box styles to allow exactly what the OP is trying to achieve. I don't see how this is false advertising.

Comment: I didn't say anything about false advertising.  "Use Bootstrap" is not relevant here.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. @cimmanon I think that settles this argument?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use the `<label>`´s "for"-attribute to link the label to the input-field:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
         <input id="name" type="text" value='Name'/><br />
```

And then, no: if you want to "group them together", in a box with borders for example, the best is to use div. That´s my opinion.

EDIT:
I´m not that good at reading the whole question before I answer.

I agree that you should take a look at a responsive framework if you want to make things easier for you when you create web pages that should look great on mobile as well as desktop.
Twitter bootstrap is one: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/
Foundation is another: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Find one you like and try it out. Personally, I like Bootstrap the most.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to see radio buttons and checkboxes element tuples wrapped from the label, like this:

```
<label> <input /> text </label>
```

However you will find more and better examples on bootstrap.